# How to create 2 separated xAxis chart

Tags: highcharts

I want to create like below graph. How can I create like this graph?

The biggest value has to be in the middle of xAxis.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **xAxis.categories** to set the xAxis labels and next you need to define the **x** value for each point in the data.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e7d6c2pm/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'scatter'
  },

    xAxis: {
    categories: ['0m', '150m', '250m', '350m', '550m', '700m', '550m', '350m', '150m', '0m'],
    plotLines: [{
        value: 5,
      color: 'red'
    }]
  },

  series: [{
    data: [[0.1, 52], [2, 20], [3, 10], [2.5, 8], [2.8, 13]]
  }, {
    data: [[6, 52], [8, 20], [9, 10], [8.5, 8], [7, 13]]
  }]
});
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories

Comment: Cool, Thanks Sebastian

Comment: Hi @sebastian, 
I should present same xAxis values seperated. for example: 

`series: [{
    data1: [[0.1, 52], [2, 20], [3, 10], [2.5, 8], [2.8, 13]]
  }, {
    data2: [[0.1, 52], [2, 20], [3, 10], [2.5, 8], [2.8, 13]]
  }]`

data1 should coming to the left side at xAxis, data2 should coming to the right side at xAxis.

Comment: I am afraid that it is impossible to achieve in one chart. Notice that x = 5 is a point where is the line dividing the chart. So every x less than 5 will be rendered on the left side and x more than 5 will be rendered on the right side.

Comment: Yeap, I did this, but I am looking for more useful way. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You can always create a function which will be adding the 5 to the x values.